# Build Jade automatic in sublime 3 - SublimeOnSaveBuild

Tags: sublimetext3

Does anyone know how to make SublimeOnSaveBuild automatically detected Jade?

I would like to use the Automatic feature to compile whatever file I have open. Switching between SCSS and Jade.

I have SCSS build & Jade Build plugins installed and If I selected them separately they will compile fine. If I select automatic, the SCSS will compile but Jade will not, getting the Error, no build system. I added jade to SublimeOnSaveBuild.sublime-setting

[Jade/Sass build plugins installed, Automatic setting doesn't detect Jade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzagR.png)

[Added jade to the sublime-settings file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ZWU.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, had to write my own Sass and Jade Builds. Just modify the output directory to your needs and you should be good. Here they are:

Sass

```
{

    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${project_path}/Project/Web/css/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--style", "compressed", "--no-cache", "--sourcemap=none"],
    "selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }

}
```

Jade

```
{
    "cmd": ["jade", "$file", "-E", "php", "-P", "-o", "$project_path/Project/Web/php"],
    "selector": ["source.jade"],
    "osx": {"path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"},
    "windows": {"shell": "true"}
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  I just added the Jade build you typed up and changed it for HTML and its automatically detected now. I'd give you up vote, but I dont have enough reputation yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete package control installed package and put into ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages ST2 packages, works for me.